# how to protect the history of all users in linux without .bash_history file

Tags: linux

We are in the process of setting up an environment where we should be able to trace who did what in a server. We generally concentrate on "last" command and bash_history file still it didn't help us perfectly. I.e. still the same user who executed the commands can remove the entries from bash_history file. So it's getting difficult to trace it.

Is there a possible way of completely protecting their command history?

Answer (score 3):

Don't rely on `.bash_history`.  Enable accounting (read about `accton(8)` and friends), then give people admin rights only through `sudo`.  Make `sudo` log commands, and send the logs to a remote machine.

Comment: That is a completely different interpretation of  'completely protecting their command history' than I thought of. +1 anyway. Sending the logs to a remote machine is the safest, but only necessary if a user could become `root`. Otherwise logging to the service on the local machine (that writes the log inaccessible to the user) would be good enough.

Comment: @Anthon I was assuming the question was about accountability of "junior admins".  For "mortal" users, `accton(8)` should be enough to tell which user is up to something.  Trying to protect shell history is pointless, it's just to easy to overcome.

Comment: Actually they have access only through sudo, still they can delete their history right? and i will explore this acct option thank you :)

Comment: @Nishanth Like I said, enable accounting.  Logging `sudo` commands can give you more details too.

Comment: The whole description is a little vague, I did not see anything about junior admins not even between the lines.

Comment: @Anthon True, but monitoring junior admins is the only interesting case.  Keeping normal users in check is a problem solved a long time ago, with limits, accounting, and logs.

Comment: @Anthon yes it is not about the sudo user who have access to root, its all about an normal user who is having access to an application user of a webserver.

Comment: @Nishanth In both cases they can completely protect their history file from spying by not writing it at all. That is the answer to the question you wrote in your post. But it looks like what you really should have asked is: how can I prevent them from protecting their history?

Comment: @anthon, yes exactly this is what i should know, sorry for the confusion :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a possible way of completely protecting their command history?

Yes there is a possible way for the user to completely protect their command history. They should just do

```
unset HISTFILE
```

and they are completely protected from anyone spying on their history, as it will not be written to disc anymore.

Comment: Hi @Anthon, I think the OP wants just the opposite of your answer and is looking the secure the history (in fact, all that the users are doing) to be able to track down what happened on the systems.

Comment: @Lambert I know they want to spy. But he is asking if they can (further) completely protect their history. They can, by not writing it out in the first place. So it is clear from my answer that kludging with the .bash_history is not going to work. Asking for a different solution would require a different question. Now that may be what the OP wanted to ask, but it was not what **was** asked.

Comment: I fully agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a situation where a user would edit and/or delete his .bash_history in order to cover his tracks.

A simple solution I rolled out was to use chattr +a which only allows the file to be appended, not edited or deleted. Also, only the root user can set it or unset it.

To deploy to all current users, su to root and run:

```
chattr +a /home/*/.bash_history
```

To pick up any and all new users, I wrote a simple script to run this command every 30 minutes.

Keep in mind that before you can delete a user's directory in the event the user is being removed, this has to be changed. This is done by running:

```
chattr -a /home/username/.bash_history
```

It has proven to be quite effective. Now, I just need to find the equivalent on AIX.

Comment: This works until the user runs `exec dash` or some other shell that doesn't use .bash_history. Also, this doesn't necessary work if the home directories are on an NFS file system.